# Updating member variable of object while using multprocessing pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a class `B` which is composed of another class `A`.

In class `B` I am using multiprocessing pool to call a method from class `A`. This method updates a member variable of `A` (which is a dict).

When I print out this member variable it doesn't seem to have been updated. Here is the code describing the issue:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.aDict = {'key': 0}

    def set_lock(self, lock):
        self.lock = lock

    def do_work(self, item):
        print("Doing work for item: {}".format(item) )
        self.aDict['key'] += 1

        return [1,2,3] # return some list

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.objA = A()

    def run_with_mp(self):
        items=['item1', 'item2']
        with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
            result = pool.map_async(self.objA.do_work, items)
            result.wait()
            pool.terminate()

        print(self.objA.aDict)

    def run(self):
        items=['item1', 'item2']
        for item in items:
            self.objA.do_work(item)

        print(self.objA.aDict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.run_with_mp() # prints {'key': 0}
    b.run()         # prints {'key': 2}
```

`b.run_with_mp()` prints `{'key': 0}` whole `b.run()` prints `{'key': 2}`. I thought the multiprocessing pool version would also do the same since the object `self.objA` had scope for the full class of `B` where the multiprocessing pool runs.

I think each worker of the pool sees a different version of `self.objA`, which are different from the one in the main program flow. Is there a way to make all the workers update a common variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to the explanation, indeed, each spawned process holds its own area of memory, it means that they are independent. When you run the `do_work` each process updates its version of `aDict` because that variable it's not shared. If you want to share a variable, the easiest way is to use a `Manager`, for example:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.aDict = mp.Manager().dict({'key': 0})

    def set_lock(self, lock):
        self.lock = lock

    def do_work(self, item):
        print("Doing work for item: {}".format(item) )
        self.aDict['key'] += 1

        return [1,2,3] # return some list

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.objA = A()

    def run_with_mp(self):
        items=['item1', 'item2']
        with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
            result = pool.map_async(self.objA.do_work, items)
            result.wait()
            pool.terminate()

        print(self.objA.aDict)

    def run(self):
        items=['item1', 'item2']
        for item in items:
            self.objA.do_work(item)

        print(self.objA.aDict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.run_with_mp() # prints {'key': 2}
    b.run()         # prints {'key': 4}
```

I modified your example to share the `aDict` variable, so each process will update that property (`run_with_mp` and `run` methods). Consider reading more in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works when I used the dict() from mp.Manager() if I use a simple dictionary. When I have other objects as value for a key inside dict, for example `self.aDict = mp.Manager().dict({'key': set()}) ` and in `do_work()`, I do `self.aDictt['key'].add(item)` it doesn't seem to work. The set() is always empty. Is this how it is supposed to be?

Comment: @Bharat Yes, it's a known problem, this is a SO question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510076/unable-to-update-nested-dictionary-value-in-multiprocessings-manager-dict. Basically, try to share simple objects,.

Comment: Thanks, I used the way described in answer to that question, where I get the value from dict, add items and then assign it back to the key. This works.